# error in swapping two lines in insert last function of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I don't understand one thing in insert-last function in singly linked list.this function will insert new item after last node always.

```
newNode->next=temp->next;
temp->next=newNode;
```

I got an error. I don't know why? please help!!

```
int insertLast(int item)
{

    struct listNode *newNode,*temp;
    newNode=(struct listNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));

    newNode->item=item;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    if(list==NULL)
    {
        list=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=list;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)temp=temp->next;
        newNode->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=newNode;
    }
    return SUCCESS_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: What error? How are newNode and temp defined?

Comment: edited!please check the code! thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting specifically? I'm assuming list is the name of the head of the list, what's the scope of it? We still need more information

Comment: Is there an error swapping the 2 mentioned lines?? The first line doesn't do anything and is useless.

Comment: not an error exactly! after run the code it stopped working! :( 
yap 1st 2 lines are those lines that are being swapped and then code does not run saying stopped working ..

Comment: well...if you swap those two lines, you correctly assign newNode at the end of the list, but end up making the 'next' element of the newNode point to itself, which will of course produce weird results and is very very incorrect. Why would you need to swap those lines?

Comment: ohhh I get it now!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newNode->next=temp->next;
```

`NewNode->next` should stay `null` since you are adding to the end of the list. Right now your list will have a circle in the end (temp->newNode->temp->newNode...) so you will not be able to go through it.